# Doubts about Stored XSS Vulnerability

Tags: force.com, security

In the following examples, is it necessary to apply HTMLENCODE?

```
{!$Label.Select_Your_Language} : Custom label 
{!lang.Name}  : SF Custom Object 
{!HotelConfig.languages} : apex class Variable 
{!uNights} : apex class Variable
```

Codigo:

```
<apex:define name="langs-list">
    <h3>{!$Label.Select_Your_Language}</h3>
    <ul>
        <apex:repeat value="{!HotelConfig.languages}" var="lang">
            <li class="{!IF(lang.name==langCode,'selected','')}"><a href="dhotel__t_home?l={!lang.Name}">{!lang.Title__c}</a></li>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ul>
</apex:define>



<apex:outputPanel id="htnights">
       <input type="text" id="nights" readonly="true" value="{!uNights}"/>
    <apex:inputHidden id="nightsHidden" value="{!uNights}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: You can format code blocks in your question by selecting the text and using the pre-formatted button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of good worked examples on preventing XSS vulnerabilities in the [Secure Coding Cross Site Scripting: S-Control Template and Formula Tags](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting#S-Control_Template_and_Formula_Tags) developer force article.
The examples include when you should use HTMLEncode versus URLENCODE, JSINHTMLENCODE etc... See [Encoding Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm#heading_2_1).

- **Custom label**: `<h3>{!$Label.Select_Your_Language}</h3>`
  Yes, I'd apply HTMLEncode here unless you specifically want to allow those with permissions to set the label to include HTML characters.
- **SF Custom Object Name in hyperlink**: `<a href="dhotel__t_home?l={!lang.Name}">`
  Yes, I'd apply URLENCODE here
- **Apex class variable**: `<apex:repeat value="{!HotelConfig.languages}" var="lang">`
  Here the value will never be directly rendered to the client so it shouldn't be an issue.
- **Apex class Variable**: `<input type="text" id="nights" readonly="true" value="{!uNights}"/>`
  It depends on how uNights is being set. If in any way the value could have been defined by the user than I would HTMLEncode it. If you have complete control of the value with no user input included then you don't need to.
- **Apex class Variable**: `<apex:inputHidden id="nightsHidden" value="{!uNights}"/>`
  With other apex controls like apex:outputText the value will be encoded by default and if you want the unencoded value you must explicitly set escape="false". apex:inputHidden doesn't have the corresponding attribute so I suspect it is always encoded.